# "Read Receipt" indicator

Tags: microsoft-outlook

There *used* to be a way in Outlook that one could prove that they requested a read receipt on a message (I don't remember what the indicator was). We've updated to Outlook 2010, and it seems that the *only* way to prove that you requested a receipt is by actually getting the receipt.

This is to say, how can I look at a message that I have sent and *not* gotten a receipt back on and confirm that I did indeed request said receipt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This time I have figured it out...

Say you send an e-mail off and you send it with a return receipt requested.  A few days go by, and you see that it has not been read yet.  Now you start to second guess yourself, DID you in fact send this off with a return receipt?  You don't want to bother the person, but you may have to send a second e-mail off.  HOW can you tell if this had a receipt requested on it, IF it has not been read?  Well, there's good news.  There is a switch that you can enable to turn on an indicator.  Here is how it is enabled.  You may have to assist someone in this process some day:

1. Right click on the title bar of the "View Pane".
2. Select "View Settings".
3. Select "Columns...".
4. From the "Available Columns:" field, select "Receipt Requested" (you may have to change it to show "all mail items" to find this option).
5. Move it to the top of the "Show these columns in this order:" field.
6. Select "Ok".

EVERY SINGLE EMAIL will display a "yes" or a "no" to indicate if you have requested a receipt. Also, do this for EVERY folder that you wish to view this field in. (If you do this in your inbox it does not show on your sent items until you do the same thing on the sent items folder.) Since this switch is not normally enabled on install, you will most likely have to do this to make this indicator show up.

Possible correction:  I'm not sure if you have to do this for every folder... It may be that this only posts in your sent items folder.  I thought I saw something yesterday, but I don't see it today, therefore I am not prepared to say that this must be done from all folders or not at this point.  My current stance is that if you do this it is enabled on all folders, but I can't say for sure.  Either way, this is the proper proceedure to enable that switch--problem solved.

Comment: Nice detective work.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your sent items
- Open the sent email
- Click "File"
- To the right you will see a button for "Properties"

The properties window will open, if you requested a read receipt the box will be checked.

Comment: That is only true when a receipt request is received... I've tested that, and on e-mails that have not been read, I cannot find the difference between them and emails that I did not request a read receipt from until the email with the request is read.

Comment: Nope... another test proved that this did not work as well.  It seems to ONLY show you the receipt request indicator ONLY after you have read the receipt.

Comment: So... does anybody have any clue? BTW, BroScience, this is Outlook 2010. WHEN it does show up (after the recipient has read the message), it shows up in the ribbon bar under a section called, "Show" as an icon labled "tracking". That option, though enabled, does not appear until AFTER the person has read the message--I need it to show up IMMEDIATELY upon sending the message out...

Comment: I just tested it. I have my outlook set to ignore all read receipts. I see the indicator. Even if i don't open the mail, i still see the indicator. I am using 2010. I tested it 4 or 5 times.

Comment: What does it look like, where does it show up?  TYVM

Comment: Got it! Here's the answer...